# How does the framework know that `ModelState.IsValid` must be true in HTTPGET but false in HTTPPOST when the form fields are invalid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Consider a simple data model `Student.cs` as follows,

```
class Student
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter your name.")]   
    public string Name {get;set;}

    // other properties go here
}
```

A form view `registration.cshtml` as follows,

```
<form asp-action="Registration" method="Post">
<p>ModelState.IsVali is @ViewBag.Message</p>

<p>Data: <input asp-for="Name"></p>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And action method as follow,

```
[HttpGet]
ViewResult Registration()
{
    ViewBag.Message=ModelState.IsValid;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
ViewResult Registration(Student s)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid){
       ViewBag.Message=false;
       return View();
    }
}
```

- How does the framework know that  `ModelState.IsValid` must be true in HTTPGET but false in HTTPPOST when the form fields are invalid? For me, the blank view form delivered to the user (by the HttpGet version of the action method) should make the `ModelState.IsValid` false.
- Extra question: Why don't we need to do `return View(s);` instead of `return View();` when returning invalid form and preserving the entered data field? For me, `return View();` seems to return a blank form.

Comment: Your GET method is not receiving a model (it does not have any parameters) so nothing is ever added to `ModelState` so its always `true` (in the POST method, your method has a parameter for the model)

Comment: Extra question's explanation: The default routing engine is configured to follow action method name when returning view with empty argument. Hence, if you commit `return View()` as `ViewResult`, by default the routing schema searches for a view with same name as declared action name.

Comment: `return View();` does return a 'blank' (default instance of the) model. And if you included `<div>@Model.SomeProperty</div>` in the view it would throw an exception. The values in you form controls are populated first from `ModelState` if they exist (which they do)

Comment: Either `return View();` or `return View(s);` will work the same in the case `ModelState.IsValid` is false.

Comment: I'll add a answer shortly explaining the behavior :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a request (either GET or POST), the `DefaultModelBinder` reads values from the request (query string parameter, route values, form values etc), initializes any parameters in your method, and attempts to set their values.

In the case of your GET method, you do not have a model as a parameter, so there is nothing to initialize, and nothing to set, so nothing is ever added to `ModelState` and `ModelState.IsValid` returns `true` (it only returns false if there is a validation error as a result of setting the value of a model property).

In the case of the POST method, you have a parameter `Student s` which so a new instance of the model is initialized. If your textbox was left empty, a `ModelState` error would be added because of the `[Required]` attribute (by default, an empty string means `null`) and `ModelState.IsValid` would return `false`.

---

Using `return View();` will return the current view without passing the model to the view. Any form controls generated with the `HtmlHelper` methods use values from `ModelState` if they exist (if not, the value is read from the `ViewDataDictionary` and then from the actual model) so if you initially posted `"xyz"`, a key/value pair of `Name: "xyz"` will be added to `ModelState`. Your `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)` method finds a match in `ModelState` and the value of the textbox is set to "xyz". As proof, if in the POST method, you were to use

```
s.Name = "Another Value";
return View(s);
```

you will see that the textbox retains the original value you posted, not "Another Value"

If however you were also to include `<div>@Model.Name</div>`, a `NullReferenceException` would be thrown (because you cannot access the `Name` property of `null`) so you should always return a model to the view.